# Find Image Center

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am wondering how to find the center(image.center?) of an UIImageView in Interface Builder or by using an NSLog.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSLog (@"Center is %f, %f", image.center.x, image.center.y);